# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Installation Error : This one is very odd

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, updates

[image]

Things I tried already:

1. Made sure that Windows 10 is fully updated
2. Restarted
3. Disabled avast
4. Tried by installing vs2015.3.exe
5. Tried repairing from Programs and Features
6. Tried renaming C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18

Every time, same error showed up!

**Edit 1**

1. Emptied %temp%
2. Log file is [here.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuL8UzDQOgZphz1ubJX-gRGpZEvJ)

**Edit 2**

3. Downloaded 7GB ISO, checked integrity. Same error still!

Help, anybody?

Comment: Have you searched for what the two error codes mean? You may have to search for decimal version of the number.

Comment: I did, that is where I found things like disabling avast and renaming S-1-5-18...but there is not much help...I will try more!

Comment: To find the detail error message, your need to collect and share the VS installation log. User this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 to gather the logs, after using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder. Then upload the file to here: https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: Meanwhile, I recommend you verify the integrity of the ISO file. You can use the FCIV.exe tool： https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing/ to check the SHA1 value of the ISO, the expected value comes from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/productinfo/vs2015-sha-vs, any discrepancy means the ISO is corrupted. Before the installation, clean up the %temp% folder then run the installer as administrator. BTW, how about your internet connection? Is good or under any proxy condition…

Comment: I have not tried using ISO. I will try it today...

Comment: @Sara, Tried ISO, checked SHA1 to be correct, yet same error!

Comment: @isntn, can you collect and share your installation logs?

Comment: @isntn, Refer to the error code in your log file, you can try to run the command: sfc /scannow in the elevated command prompt as administrator and use the Fixit tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed and run it to automatically repair issues including corrupted registry keys that block you from installing or removing programs. After that, run the VS installer as administrator again. If not works, collect and share the latest installation logs.

Comment: @Sara, I used the tool, and it claimed to have fixed few entries. When I ran setup again, it finished with some errors for C++ components - which I do not need. I was so tired, did not take screen shot. For now, VS is working and show update 3 as installed. (have not checked thoroughly - as I am on to VS Code for next few days). Later, when I have free time, will try to repair. Thanks for all help, anyways.

Comment: @isntn, do you mean the VS community 2015 with update 3 already installed successfully after you run the Fixit tool or sfc /scannow command? If so, I will add this as reply, so some other community members who have the same or similar can easier search this.
If not, could you share your solution as a reply, then mark it as answer, that will help other members to find this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the error code in your log file, you can try to run the command: sfc /scannow in the elevated command prompt as administrator, then download [the Fixit tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) and run it to automatically repair issues including corrupted registry keys that block you from installing or removing programs. After that, run the VS installer as administrator and repair it.

Answer (score 1):

Control panel, repair all visual c redistribuitable vesions, right click on visual studio 2015, change, repair, this should fix the issues